# How did Stack Overflow Teams figure out my work email address?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-for-teams

A few moments ago, I received an email with a subject line `Announcing Stack Overflow for Teams` from `do-not-reply@stackoverflow.email`. Initially, it didn't perturb me because I was under the impression that it came to my personal email - an account which is associated with my Stack Overflow Profile.

It was not until I realized that the inbox belonged to my current work organization that I started to investigate this. I checked my Stack Overflow profile and couldn't find a mention of it anywhere.

One possibility (very remote though) I can think of is that someone from my workplace decided to use the SO Team feature and included me in it. However, as far as I know, I'm the only one in my office who uses Stack Overflow and I doubt that this could be the case.

As far as I can tell, I do not recall associating my Stack Overflow/Stack Overflow Meta profile with my work email. Can someone shed some light on this, please?

Comment: Are you 100% sure there is no redirection from your private to your work E-Mail? Maybe check the headers to see which address it was sent to.

Comment: Judging from your comment on Erik's answer it looks like you have more than one account. I can dig further if you want to let me know what address the email was sent to (use dward@)

Comment: @DeanWard: I hit report spam on it.

Comment: @Joshua you can unsubscribe from all emails from us in your [email settings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current)

Comment: @DeanWard: Settings page is not ADA compliant and I've never been there from before I had to care. I'm not sure I can turn the advertisements off.

Comment: @Joshua happy to do so for you. I'll bring up the accessibility issue with our design team

Comment: @Joshua What about that page isn't ADA compliant? Happy to improve things!

Comment: @AaronShekey: The on/off buttons don't provide any readback state and I think buttons are missing. I think it's another instance of this bug: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49769/may-13-2010-updates-break-high-contrast-windows-mode

Answer (score 5):

At the bottom of that mail, there's a button called *Edit email settings*. This takes you to your email settings page, where you can configure the email used by Stack Exchange for such mails.

This email address can be different from the one you used to sign up and register your account. I can only imagine you changed it yourself, as these settings don't tend to randomly change.

You can also get there by going to your email settings via the profile, or the link https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current.

Comment: That's strange. If I visit that page from the link in the email, I see my work email prepopulated in the text box. However, if I go to the same page via my SO profile settings, I see my personal email listed there.

Comment: That's certainly strange. The email link uses an authentication token, as far as I can see. It might be from a different account.

Comment: Interesting. For me the prepopulated email address is a Yahoo account I haven't used in some 20 years. Must be something to do with an old authentication association (I went a bit OTT on account associations, y'know, just in case). Does mean all the SO propaganda has been going to an unmonitored address for the past 7½ years though, nice.

Comment: ... and apparently Yahoo Mail is broken so I can't go back and see what I've missed. Oh well.